# How do we set path in img tag in html?

Tags: html

I am just a starting with html, I have an apache server running, thus my problem is with the image not loading.

I have a home page in my Apache htdocs folder in which another page **About** is hyperlinked, now in this About page is were I wanted to load the image but it doesn't work.

Here is what I used

`<img scr="C:\apache24\htdocs\COC\pictures\townhall.jpg">`

Why doesn't this work. I have tried.

`<img scr="http:\\localhost\COC\Pictures\townhall2.jpg">`

But doesn't work.

Comment: i am sorry,i dont know if this is the way to edit the question,i wanted to edit was that i made a mistake in this question i did type in src,the problem is whenever i use these or even <img src="C:/apache24/htdocs/COC/Pictures/townhall2.jpg" alt="Town Hall 2"> ,images doesnt load,but when i try to run without the apache ,it works fine,what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

It is `src` not `scr`.

So it will be :

```
<img src="C:\apache24\htdocs\COC\pictures\townhall.jpg" /> 
<img src="C:\apache24\htdocs\COC\pictures\townhall2.jpg" />
```

**Working code:**

```html
<img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1" />
```

[See this fiddle for an example](https://jsfiddle.net/0g10ewp5/)

Comment: i am sorry,i dont know if this is the way to edit the question,i wanted to edit was that i made a mistake in this question i did type in src,the problem is whenever i use these or even <img src="C:/apache24/htdocs/COC/Pictures/townhall2.jpg" alt="Town Hall 2"> ,images doesnt load,but when i try to run without the apache ,it works fine,what is the problem?

Comment: Ok so read the answer of @xdevs23, he explains why your image path could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the path C:..... Use relative paths.So if your image is `C:\apache24\htdocs\COC\pictures\townhall.jpg` and your website is in `C:\apache24\htdocs` then write `COC/pictures/townhall.jpg` as path.

And why are you loading COC images? You know that it might be a copyright infringement doing that... Or am I wrong? Whatever...

So your img tag would be:

`<img src="COC/pictures/townhall.jpg" alt="Townhall" />`
And don't forget to use `/` instead of `\` in URLs.

Comment: i am sorry,i dont know if this is the way to edit the question,i wanted to edit was that i made a mistake in this question i did type in src,the problem is whenever i use these or even <img src="C:/apache24/htdocs/COC/Pictures/townhall2.jpg" alt="Town Hall 2"> ,images doesnt load,but when i try to run without the apache ,it works fine,what is the problem?

Comment: Because apache denies access to your data except allowed paths for your website (in your case C:\apache24\htdocs\)